# Custom authentication handler for community

Tags: apex, login

how can I implement a custom auth handler for my Customer Community via Apex and log the user in (all through Apex)?

Reason: I have a Customer Community, users and all that (works fine).
The company has some kind of a legacy IdM system that they want to use to authenticate their community users.

Unfortunately that system has some proprietary third party interface, so no Oauth... It (kind of) is supposed to work like delegated authentication.

From the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthProviderPluginClass.htm) I understand I can connect to my own provider but only if it's an Oauth provider - which it is not.

Broken down it should work like this:

1. User comes to custom community login page
2. Enters username/password (u/p)
3. Apex Controller passes u/p to that IdM solution and receives a response
4. a) If response is positive, a new session should be created and user is logged in to community, 
   b) otherwise an error message should be shown.

My problem lies with 4a: Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to log a user in with Apex? Obviously I cannot use `Site.login()` as the password on the Salesforce user record won't match the one in the IdM

Can it even be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You create then use an external authentication provider, where you can call whatever you need using apex :) ( API, SOAP, HTTP .... it does not require to be OAuth )

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_authentication_providers_external.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_plugin_custom.htm&type=5

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for the links but They don't seem to address my issue. I've read through these pages beforehand. The first link relates to the setup of auth providers and explains custom registration (which I'm not looking for). The second link basically says to extends the `Auth.AuthProviderPluginClass` which is related to Oauth. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: The idea is that you totally delegate to custom apex code the identification/registration process, and there you can call your custom "not-oauth" app, it does not fit your requirement ?

Comment: in the second link: "Create a custom single sign-on (SSO) authentication provider to let users log in to your Salesforce org using their non-Salesforce credentials. Implement a custom external authentication provider if your OAuth app doesn’t support OpenID Connect. If your app supports OpenID Connect, you can use one of the authentication providers that Salesforce provides."

Comment: I get the "delegation to apex" part. However that is not my issue. Say I've verified the credentials with the 3rd party IdM. I'm now in a state in my apex code where I know 3 things: username, password and whether they are valid. My question is: How can I now log the current user (i.e. create an authenticated session) in? From how I understand https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_plugin_custom.htm&type=5 or the documentation, that custom implementation is of use when I have an Oauth-capable provider - which I have not... I already do know whether the use is allowed to log in